# Adding elements of a Json Payload in a List

Tags: json, scala, rest, playframework

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.{JsPath, Reads}

import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

class Application extends Controller {
  import play.api.libs.json.Json

  def saveStock = Action { request =>
    val json = request.body.asJson.get
    val principal = (json \ "AAA").get.as[Int]
    val upfrontValueFee = (json \ "BBB" \ "value").get.as[Int]
    val upfrontCreditlineFee = (json \"CCC" \ "value").get.as[Int]
    val id: List[String] = (json \ "DDD" \\ "id").get.as[List[Int]
    Ok("Hello")
  }
}
```

This is my code. I am creating a REST API using Play. I am taking the request payload. I have series of IDs (Int). I want to take them in a list. Can you please suggest me some solution. I have used Reads as well. But it doesnt suit my needs. I am beginner in scala and development. This is my first question in Stackoverflow. I have made some editing mistakes. I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: What exactly do you want as a result ? an example output would be good.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I want the output as follows. LIST(id1,id2,id3). When I implement the above code, it says that it cant convert the mutable list to Immutable. I tried with List Buffer also.

Comment: H, I figured a way to get it in ListBuffer. I just used                                   
     val id = json \ "schedule" \\ "id". I am able to get the ids in a listBuffer. Now I am trying to convert them into a List[Int].